# Obter a tecla pressionada com aplicação minimizada ou sem foco c#

Tags: c#

Gostaria que ao pressionar o <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> no teclado, o aplicativo em C# que está minimizado na *tray* do sistema, fosse maximizado e exibisse a imagem do *print*.

Answer (score 4):

Eu não acho que há uma maneira fácil de fazer isso, mas isso (usando windows message para implementar Global System Hook em C #) pode ajudar. Eu adicionei o código abaixo

```
 _GlobalHooks.Keyboard.KeyboardEvent += (w, l) => 
{
      this.LblKey.Text = "KEY: " + w.ToInt32().ToString("X8") + " " + l.ToInt32().ToString("X8");
};
_GlobalHooks.Keyboard.Start();
```

para o construtor de Form1 de GlobalHookTest e foi capaz de monitorar todos os eventos de teclado.

Nesse Git tem um projeto completo usando Global System Hook em C#
https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook